# Buck and Android Material theme

Tags: android, performance, buck

I am setting up Buck to speed up the build of an Android app. The app uses the Material Theme through the appcompat-v7:21.0.+ library but Buck cannot find the required resources. Any hints?

Here is the error output:

```
$ buck build //app/src/main:main                                             
Using buckd.
[-] PROCESSING BUCK FILES...FINISHED 0.4s
[+] BUILDING...2.0s (3/6 JOBS)
 |=> IDLE
 |=> IDLE
 |=> IDLE
 |=> //app/src/main:main#aapt_package...  1.5s (running aapt_package[1.5s])
Log:
No Android platform target specified. Using default: Google Inc.:Google APIs:21
app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarSize'.

app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:23: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarSize'.

app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.

app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:38: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'editTextColor'.

app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml:32: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.

BUILD FAILED: //app/src/main:main#aapt_package failed with exit code 1:
aapt_package
```

Comment: What are the contents of the `BUCK` files (I want to know dependencies are correctly set up).  Also, do you have the right build tools version?  It should be >= 21.0.1.

Comment: I just had to add android_prebuilt_aar to the root level BUCK file see: http://facebook.github.io/buck/article/exopackage.html#build-buck-support-library

Comment: Could you post the BUCK file you had at the end?

Answer (score 3):

Download appcompat-aar file and use as dependency in your anroid_resource rule

https://github.com/facebookarchive/AntennaPod/blob/buck/BUCK#L133
https://github.com/facebookarchive/AntennaPod/blob/buck/BUCK#L64